# strtok() returns weird values and segfault

Tags: c, strtok

I am using `strtok()` to extract characters from data obtained from a file.

This is my code:

```
fgets(text, 12, myFile);

printf ("text is: %s \n", &text);
char *token;
token = strtok(text, " ");
printf("first token is: %s \n", &token);

printf ("text is: %s \n", &text);
token = strtok(NULL, " ");
printf("second token is: %s \n", &token);
```

This gives the output as follows:

```
text is: 4 3       //this is the expected and correct value of "text"
first token is:  ڱ[? 
text is: 4        // I was expecting this to be 3 after getting the first token...
second token is: "ڱ[? 
Segmentation fault: 11
```

So as you can see, not only does `strtok()` not get the right values, it seems to have gone through the text in a very strange order. Any ideas on why this might be? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Is `text` a `char` pointer or an array of `char`? I expect it to be the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%s` in all those `printf` expects a `char*`. You pass `&text` and `&token` which are all `char**`s. This invokes Undefined Behavior as stated in the C11 standard:

> **7.21.6.1 The fprintf function**
>
> [...]
>
> 9. If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined. <sup>282</sup> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

To fix the problem, remove the ampersands from all those `printf`s ,i.e, replace all the below statements:

```
printf ("text is: %s \n", &text);
printf("first token is: %s \n", &token);
printf ("text is: %s \n", &text);
printf("second token is: %s \n", &token);
```

with

```
printf ("text is: %s \n", text);
printf("first token is: %s \n", token);
printf ("text is: %s \n", text);
printf("second token is: %s \n", token);
```

Comment: Just interested from which website did you copied the quote?

Comment: @Rizier123 , [Google for "n1570"](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=n1570). It'll give you [this](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html). It is a draft of the C11 standard.